# Spring Batch task is getting shutdown before RSocket proxy scrapes metrics from it

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I am using Spring Cloud Dataflow to launch batch jobs that are wrapped in Spring Cloud task and we also have configured Prometheus and Rsocket proxy to scrape task related metrics. To make the tasks shutdown, I am using `spring.cloud.task.closecontext_enabled=true`. But we observed that few metrics are not getting scraped because of this closecontext flag(if it is set to false, metrics are scraped as intended but the pods are not getting shutdown so increase in TCO).
I suspect that the rsocket proxy is unable to get the metrics before the tasks get shutdown. Can someone know this issue and can show some pointers in solving this issue?

Comment: Which version of Spring cloud Task and prometheus-rsocket-proxy do you use? Is your issue similar to https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/prometheus-rsocket-proxy/issues/35?

Comment: Below are the versions used:
spring-cloud-starter-task - 2.3.0
prometheus-rsocket-client - 1.3.0
prometheus-rsocket-proxy-server - 1.3.0
prometheus-rsocket-proxy(server image) - 0.11.0

Comment: I have the same issue, I've installed prometheus and prometheus-proxy from the latest repository version v2.9.1 (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow), prometheus-rsocket-client 1.3.0.

Comment: @Kranthi I get the same issue, though my setup is local with docker-compose. have u solved the issue?